# Group by one column from joined table 1 but show based on the latest records from table 2 in descending order

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables

**subscribers**

```
subscriberid | phone
--------------------
 1           | (555) 555-5554
 2           | (555) 555-5555
```

**messages**

```
messageid | message        | subscriberid
---------------------------------------
 1        | Hello          | 1
 2        | Hello Again    | 1
 3        | Hey            | 2
 4        | Hey Again      | 2
```

I would like to GROUP BY the Phone in the subscribers table but show the latest message from the second table for that subscriberid.

My query so far is this, but it's only giving me the earliest message not the latest.

```
SELECT s.phone, MAX(m.messageid), m.message 
FROM subscribers s 
INNER JOIN messages m ON m.subscriberid = s.subscriberid 
GROUP BY s.phone 
ORDER BY m.messageid DESC
```

How can I get this query to return these results

```
messageid         | message  
---------------------------------------
 (555) 555-5554   | Hello Again
 (555) 555-5555   | Hey Again
```

Comment: Youк query is wrong. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY for to ensure. *it's only giving me the earliest message not the latest* No, it gives randon from all possible - now it is randomly the latest.

Comment: @Strawberry sorry I thought I included every thing I could possibly include. Both table structures, my query and the intended results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One correct version of what you were trying to do joins to a subquery which finds, for each subscriber, the latest message:

```sql
SELECT
    m1.messageid,
    m1.message
FROM subscribers s
INNER JOIN messages m1
    ON m1.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT subscriberid, MAX(messageid) AS max_messageid
    FROM messages
    GROUP BY subscriberid
) m2
    ON m2.subscriberid = m1.subscriberid AND
       m2.max_messageid = m1.messageid;
```

See the answer by @akina for a more modern solution using analytic functions.  His approach would be appropriate if you are running MySQL 8 or later.

Comment: OMG Tim this was it!! It provides the exact results I was looking for. I didn't even realize you could inner join a subquery!

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS ( SELECT s.phone, 
                     m.message, 
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.phone ORDER BY m.messageid) rn
              FROM subscribers s 
              INNER JOIN messages m USING (subscriberid) )
SELECT phone, message
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1;
```

Comment: I'm getting unrecognized statement near WITH. mysql version shows Ver14.14

Comment: @Omar *mysql version shows Ver14.14* Not exists. Show FULL version string.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do:

```
SELECT  phone, message 
FROM (select *, MAX(messageid) OVER(PARTITION BY subscriberid) grp FROM messages) m
JOIN subscribers s
ON m.subscriberid = s.subscriberid
WHERE grp = messageid
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT s.phone, m.message 
FROM subscribers s 
INNER JOIN messages m ON m.subscriberid = s.subscriberid 
GROUP BY s.phone 
ORDER BY MAX(m.messageid) DESC
```